# Make an endpoint in a single page application which doesn't serve the html file

Tags: express, server, routes, single-page-application

I m using express to make a server.

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```

For every endpoint, I serve the same HTML. I handle the routes on the client-side.
How do I make an endpoint such that it doesn't server "index.html".
I tried adding

```
app.get("/abc", (req, res) => {
    res.json(some data);
});
```

But it sends the index.html file

Comment: You need to move the `.get("/*"` to the end, and/or (as I do [here](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/master/server/app.js)) have a specific prefix for API routes that is excluded from the push-state handling.

Answer (score 0):

Express basically checks if the requested route matches the ones you've specified (from top to bottom). If it does, it follows the given instructions. The very first route you've specified is `/*` which means it will match any `GET` request that the user asks for. Since it has found a match, it will not proceed to check the other routs. So instead, you want to specify a route like this at the very end so that it checks the other routs first.

```js
app.get("/abc", (req, res) => {
    res.json({"key": "value"});
});

/*
    This route has to be placed at the end
    (just before the listener)
 */
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```